# terraform replace multiple values in arbitrary non-HCL templated string, using map

Tags: terraform

I am looking to replicate [templatefile()](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile), but with a different regex than the usual `${...}`. The source here is js code, which already uses`${...}` syntax for other purposes, messing up the terraform templating.

E.g. my input map may be:

```
variable "values" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "a" = "Was A"
    "b" = "Hello world"
  }
}
```

My input is something like:

```
This is my input with [a] over and [a] over and [b] multiple times [a] and [b],
and I already use ${somevar} and ${anothervar} for something unrelated.
```

I want to replace every case of `[a]` with its value in the map, same for `[b]`.

Sort of:

```
templatefile_alternate("path/to/file", var.values, "[]")
```

which says, "don't look for `${a}` and `${b}`, but instead `[a]` and `[b]`.

I could use [replace](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/replace), but then I end up having to chain one after the other, and getting a loop is difficult:

```
out = replace(replace(in, "[a]",var.values[a]), "[b]", var.values[b])
```

If there are more than 1 or 2 items, it is unmanageable.